Tomboy movie, the girl lives with her father, because her mother died
So, I want to watch this movie, I watched it with my friends but it was a really good movie. It's about a girl, who lives with her father. Her father I think repairs cars. At the beginning of the movie she switches schools, she falls in love with this boy and turns from a tomboy into a sassy and popular girl. Oh yeah, and in the beginning she is popular although she doesn't want to be.
If you know the name please tell me.

When did you see the movie and what year possibly is the movie (general time frame)? Any notable actors? Anything else? You really don't give us much to go on here.

A year ago, well I dont know the name of the actor, but she had long light blonde hair, yeah I know its not allot but if I knew more I would have written it.

This plot reminded me of Mean Girls and I think its TV sequel Mean Girls 2 from 2011 actually fits your description. The heroine is a blonde tomboy and a transfer student who lives with her dad (who's a NASCAR mechanic) and the plot revolves around the cliques in her new school. Here's a more detailed Wiki description and the trailer. 

Sounds like...1985, Just One of the Guys, is the movie you are referencing I believe ...she ends up attending another school as a boy, to get a story published in that school on how girls are dicriminated against...to prove a point to one of her teachers at her original school who didn't take her serious as a girl. It's pretty good how the guy she ends up liking at the other school does a "lunch table tip-over", tribute to the school bully.
Hope this helps!

No offence, BB Stacker, but the heroine in that movie isn't a blonde, has both parents and the original question wasn't about a girl disguised as a boy but about a tomboy who becomes a popular girl.

I must've gotten that one in reverse!
